# Using don't cares to reduce a function

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

We have the function: f = p'*c' + p*b' + qc

With satisfiability don't cares given by SDC = {p*b, q'*b', q*b*c, q'*c'}

The K-map for the function is :

```
      \ b'*c' | b'*c | b*c | b*c'
p'*q' |   1   |  0   |  0  |  1
p'*q  |   1   |  1   |  1  |  1
p*q   |   1   |  1   |  1  |  0
p*q'  |   1   |  1   |  0  |  0
```

and using the "don't cares" in the k-map gives the unfilled k-map

```
      \ b'*c' | b'*c | b*c | b*c'
p'*q' |   X   |  X   |  0  |  X
p'*q  |   1   |  1   |  X  |  1
p*q   |   1   |  1   |  X  |  X
p*q'  |   X   |  X   |  X  |  X
```

Why does the book say that the minimized function is

f = p'c' + q

when the k-map indicates that the function should be

f = q

Did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: I think I get the same thing as you.

Comment: @DKNguyen the book uses logic to simplify the expression; maybe it is not fully minimized?

Comment: What do you mean it uses logic? You mean reduction through equations instead of via K-map? I never had to do reductions through equations with don't cares.

Comment: I get the same k-maps, as well as the same optimized result (which is obviously valid by inspection.) The book has an error either in the assumptions being transcribed to the book incorrectly or else faulty logic. ;)

Comment: @jonk im going to give the author the benefit of the doubt and say my transcription is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It has been pointed out that there may be a transcription error, and the consensus is that the problem as stated with my result is in fact correct.

Comment: That is more a comment than an answer. But I'll +1 the question.